# HIve2 with Tez gives Execution Error

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2, tez, apache-tez

I am using Hive2 with Tez. When I run the query it gives execution error which shown below.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask

ERROR [432a4475-d246-4596-ad4c-54de6fea86c8 main] exec.Task: Failed to execute tez graph.
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string

Comment: Look on your job history and check the logs of the Tez tasks

Comment: *exec.Task: Job Submission failed with exception 'java.lang.I
llegalArgumentException(Can not create a Path from an empty string)'*

Comment: `exec.Task: Failed to execute tez graph.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string`

Comment: Add the full exception stack from the log to your post

Comment: @RemusRusanu oky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put tez tar into local hdfs (/user/hadoop/tez) also set this path `tez.lib.uris` in tez-site.xml (tez/conf/tez-site.xml).